# How do I change the background dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a weather App and I want to change the background dynamically according to the fetched data from the API.

I have created a variable and an if statement but I was having trouble assigning the variable because I was using module.scss and I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
render() {


let bgColorClass = 'App'; // very-warm, warm, normal, cold, very-cold

if (this.state.main === "rain") {
  bgColorClass = 'rain';
 }
else if (this.state.main === "thunderstorm") {
  bgColorClass = 'thunder';
}
else if (this.state.main === "drizzle") {
  bgColorClass = 'drizzle';
}
else if (this.state.main === "Snow") {
  bgColorClass = 'snow';
}
else if (this.state.main === "Clear") {
  bgColorClass = 'sun';
}
else if (this.state.main === "Clouds") {
bgColorClass = 'clouds';
} else {
bgColorClass = 'else'
}

  return (
<div className={Styles.App} style={{bgColorClass}}>
  <Header />
  <Form
    getWeather={this.getWeather} />
<Weather 
  temperature={this.state.temperature}
  city={this.state.city}
  country={this.state.country}
  description={this.state.description}
  main={this.state.main}
```

Right now it's not working. I have defined the css files as this:

```
$sun: #ffc600;
$rain: #94AF10;
$drizzle: #06799F;
$thunder: #233884;
$snow: #707ba5;
$clouds: #686b77;
$else: #842343;

.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: $drizzle;
  //background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(66, 61, 160) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;


  &.sun{ background-color: $sun; }
  &.rain { background-color: $rain; }
  &.drizzle { background-color: $drizzle; }
  &.thunder { background-color: $thunder; }
  &.snow { background-color: $snow; }
  &.clouds { background-color: $clouds; }
  &.else { background-color: $else; }

}
```

Comment: classname should be  `className={"App   "  + bgColorClass} `

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are echoing a single word into the inline `style` attribute, which isn't valid CSS. You will need to add the `bgColorClass` to the `className` attribute of your `div`.

BTW you're using tons of if statements. You also can use a `switch` statement

```js
switch (this.state.main) {
  case "rain":
    bgColorClass = "rain";
    break;
  case "drizzle":
    bgColorClass = "drizzle";
    break;
  // and so on…
  default:
    bgColorClass = "else";
    break;
}
```

or even better: Rename all your CSS classes to the possible state values and directly insert the value as the class:

```
<div className={"App " + this.state.main}>
// e.g. if this.state.main is 'rain', then the output would be
<div class="App rain">
```

With this trick you can omit the conditional `if` or `switch` statements

Answer (score 1):

add `bgColorClass` in your `className`

example:

```
<div className={"App "+ bgColorClass}>
```